# Analytics is only showing 5 days of data. Site has been up for months

Tags: wordpress, google-analytics

My wordpress site has a google analytics plug-in that shows all my data just fine (thankfully, I'm able to see my analytics through it). But actual google analytics itself only shows the past 5 days of data...all other dates reflect 0's. I don't know how to remedy this problem or why this is happening. When other websites ask to see my website data through google analytics, it connects fine but reflects poorly because of the insufficient data. Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: Pretty much the only thing that come to mind is that maybe you are looking at a view in GA that has been set up only recently (GA views only show data from the day they were created, if the account has been running previously).

Comment: The first thing we would want to know is how many views you have in your GA property.  If there is more than 1, do the other views show complete data? As @EikePierstorff mentioned, a view will not show historical data prior to when the view was created.  You might also check that you don't have any filters set up in your view that might be excluding data.